# Unintended exit of tmux session when doing Ctrl-r to search history on zsh

Tags: zsh, tmux

I'm `tmux` with `zsh`, and I'm having issues with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. Searching back through old commands works fine but the moment nothing else is found, the `tmux` session exits.

Any way to avoid the session exiting? Maybe a way to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> in `tmux`?

Comment: I'm having the same issue afer enabling `"^R" history-incremental-pattern-search-backward`. did you end up finding a solution/cause?

Comment: Something that helped me massively was to enable `set -o xtrace` on zsh, to find out what's going on. These other articles on [how to debug zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356276/zsh-is-crashing-on-my-linux-environment-looking-for-debug-tips) and [how to capture xtrace output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336576/how-to-capture-the-xtrace-output-only-in-a-file) helped figuring out the problem (in my case, an incompatibility of powerlevel10k and pattern-search).

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is probably not normal behaviour but you don't give enough information to guess what is happening.

If tmux is crashing and you can't attach to the same session again then you should make sure it still happens with the latest tmux version and if so open a bug report.

Comment: It's possible to read the question as it being _the Z shell_ that is crashing, with tmux happily carrying on.

Comment: tmux crashes and can't attach to it any more.